# Invoke a custom code on internet connectivity in Android

Tags: android, service, push-notification, background-service

I want to get latest updates from my server when I turn on the internet and generate a notification, but when the app is closed/killed/swiped from recent items, there is no way to keep my service alive and listening to network change event so that I can ping my server, I'm not sure how to do it and how other apps such as whatsapp does it when we receive new notification the moment we turn on mobile internet.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a background service... Try workmanager..

Answer (score 0):

Making clear what @GobuCSG commented. You have the following options:

1. Run your application all the time via a foreground service and listen for wifi connected broadcast. This is **not** a good solution and wastes battery life.
2. Schedule jobs using the [WorkManager API](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

The WorkManager API was developed specifically for the purpose you specified. The API allows you to set required conditions for your job to run, such as network connectivity. It also persists scheduled jobs through device reboots, so you don't have to. The only downside is that you don't have fine tune control of *when* the code runs, as one of the goals of WorkManager is to save battery life by delaying and batching jobs.

EDIT:
Another option is to use [push notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). This is useful if your are developing a messaging app and you want your server to *push* a message to the client so they can be notified of a received message. But, if all you need to do is establish contact with your server once a day, then you should use WorkManager.